# Listener for state changes in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a component with a couple of input fields that updates the state of the component using the `valueLink={this.linkState('foo')}` facility provided by `React.addons.LinkedStateMixin`.

Prior to this I was using the `onChange` handler to communicate the changes back to the server using a websocket connection, so I was wondering if I could replicate this behaviour somewhat and post the changes in the state back using a "state change listener" of some sorts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the method I am looking for is [componentDidUpdate()](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate)

Comment: This is correct, but if there are instances where the state changes but you don't want to always do something, shouldComponentUpdate might be useful.

Comment: Right but if the state changes in a component and you don't re-render (due to something in `shouldComponentUpdate`) why would you care about the change?